# Should you use synchronized with DAOs

Tags: java, hibernate, synchronization

Ok so I understand what synchronized does and I know that it should be used when two methods access the same piece of data.

Now I have Hibernate DAO methods which update and read from a database. None of the methods share any data objects although they do access the same database (So one of the methods updates it and others read from it). Should I synchronize these methods? Or should synchronized only be used for data objects and not data in a database?

Comment: There is dirty checking concept in hibernate. You can use this instead of synchronization, cause it will slow your process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should synchronize if concurrent executions of the method in different threads may cause problems. If your method in itself is thread-safe (i.e. no shared data) it depends on whether the resources you are using in the methods are thread-safe.

In case of a Hibernate database I think synchronization is not necessary. (just a guess, without seeing the code).  Hibernate and the Database itself are pretty good in keeping their data consistent. (provided your DB and Hibernate setup is OK)

One more point to consider: synchronized code always carries the danger of deadlocks. This is especially true if you keep resources locked for a long time, like a DB-call.

So, in short: without knowing more of your application and setup: I would not synchronize this method. (YMMV)

Comment: Thanks, I think I should be alright without it so.

Answer (score 4):

Its nice if you synchronize your methods so when you writing data to the DB and same time your read method execute then there is possibilities that you will get old data in output not the currently updated data.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, so yes synchronized can be used in this case.

Comment: yes, in this case you will always get the latest updated data in output.

Answer (score 1):

You should use locking in this place, When the first method update the data then only other method should read it.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

Answer (score 0):

Whether your program will fail or not depends on how your code is organized and what it is trying to do. 
However, sharing the connection among threads is not a good practice, as you face issues with transaction management and its associate isolation.